# not getting the firestore data in html webpage

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to paginate the collection from the firestore database in html page, but the below javascript code is giving me the error, I am new to the firebase , suggest me the solution for the problem, error comes from the catch block

Error

> Error: TypeError: container is null

Code

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const loading = document.querySelector('.loading');
// store last document retrieved
let latestDoc = null;

const getNextReviews = async(doc) => {
    db.collection("noodles_nv").
    get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                let data = doc.data();

                console.log('data here' + data.docId);

                let template = `  <div class="card">
            <h2>${data.hasImage}</h2>
            <p>Written by ${data.itemCategory}</p>
            <p>Rating - ${data.itemName} </p>                
          </div>
                      `;

                container.innerHTML += template;
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    
                let table = document.getElementById('myTable')                   

                table.innerHTML += template
                console.log(doc.id, " =>datadetails", doc.data());
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {

            console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
        });

    loading.classList.add('active');
   

    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());

    container.innerHTML += template;
    loading.classList.remove('active');

    // update latest doc
    latestDoc = data.docs[data.docs.length - 1];

    // unattach event listeners if no more docs
    if (data.empty) {
        loadMore.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
        container.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }
}

// load data on DOM loaded
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => getNextReviews());

// load more docs (button)
const loadMore = document.querySelector('.load-more button');

const handleClick = () => {        
    getNextReviews(latestDoc)
}

loadMore.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// load more books (scroll)
const handleScroll = () => {

    let triggerHeight = container.scrollTop + container.offsetHeight;
    if (triggerHeight >= container.scrollHeight) {
        getNextReviews(latestDoc);
    }
}

container.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
```

I tried to paginate the data from firestore database, but there comes an error in retrieving the data

Comment: It looks like `document.querySelector('.container')` returns `null`, so you'll want to see if your HTML actually has a `.container` element.

Comment: As @Frank points out, this is likely an issue with your HTML.  *Read the error message*.  It clearly indicates a problem with the variable `container` having a `null` value.  This has nothing to do with Firebase/Firestore.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  Hi Frank, HNY, the html document does have 'containter' element

Comment: That's your problem then, as your code depends on having such an element: `const container = document.querySelector('.container');`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , I replaced the "querySelector" with "getElementById" and now I am getting the data in the console but not in the html page

Comment: and I am getting the error of "Error: TypeError: table is null"

Comment: Since the error message looks similar, I'd expect the problem to be similar too. Check where you initialize `table` and see if that element actually exists.